# LinkedIn API App - "Resource search does not exist"/"Empty oauth2 access token"

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

I am working on a simple searching app using LinkedIn's API.

I have set my base-url for the LinkedIn Sales Navigator to:

`base_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/search"`

I have also obviously added my client_id, client_secret, and access_token in the headers.

However, upon running the program, I am getting the error:
`{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Resource search does not exist","status":404}`

This makes me think that there is a problem with the base-url. But then, upon visiting the link my program is trying to visit, I am met with a JSON that says:

`serviceErrorCode    65604 message "Empty oauth2 access token" status  401`

However, as far as I am concerned, I have gone through the OAuth2 flow correctly and in full.

But I'm not sure what it actually is.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which API docs are you using for your calls? The docs for the Sales Navigator API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/sales/) don't mention a search endpoint, so your URL appears to be wrong. In regards to auth, are you wanting to perform 2-legged or 3-legged OAuth? If by "visiting the link," you mean you navigated to it in your browser, that would explain the message since you wouldn't be passing a token in via the browser.

Please share additional details/screenshots (with sensitive information redacted) to help us better understand what you've tried and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

this search point is depreciated. this is allowed to the selected developer only. First, make sure that you have the permissions for that. For reference, you can visit this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-search?view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=curl)

The other thing, if you have permission, then you need to pass the bearer token in the header for authorization.

```
 curl --location --request GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/search' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}' \
```

The complete information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-search?view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=curl).